# differentiability with complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defined by $f(z)=z^{3}$. Prove that does not exist a point $z_0$ for the line segment that joins $z_1=1$ and $z_2=i$ such that

$f(z_2)-f(z_1)=f'(z_0)(z_2-z_1)$

...any idea how to start, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: This is really equivalent to asking whether there exists a $z_0$ on this line segment for which

$$-i - 1 = f'(z_0) (i - 1)$$

or even better,

$$f'(z_0) = i$$

Now try showing that for any $z_0$ on this line segment, $3z_0^2 \ne i$. Try considering absolute values.